How do I get a table of content with initial content in Tiptap?
I'm so frustrated with Tiptap's table of contents extension. I have initial content. However, the table of contents will be empty on page load.
As I have content in the editor I would expect, that the TOC already reflects this. But it's empty, until I edit the content manually.
Even the official Tiptap template has this issue: https://templates.tiptap.dev/rw9fKC8JrC
I have tried to setup a basic react app using Tiptap's template. And I simply can't get the TOC to show up after page load.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I don't think showing code is necessary. Please only answer if you are familiar with this issue.

Make sure to set the 'emitUpdate' parameter to 'true' when setting the content. This will signal the extension to update the table of content.
editor.commands.setContent(content, true)

